# How to find the text in the below HTML tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

[I have attached the image. Need to print error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WLVQ.png)

How do i print that error message using selenium

Comment: Please put the HTML tag inside your question. This is easier. Also, what is the error you are getting? I see you are using gettext(). Doesn't this need to be getText()?

Comment: I added image kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try element.getAttribute("value")

The text property is for text within the tags of an element. For input elements, the displayed text is not wrapped by the  tag, instead it's inside the value attribute

```
WebElement error = driver.findElement(By.id("reg_error_inner")); System.out.println(error.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: Hi kindly check the added image

Comment: This won't work as the element containing the text is a div, not an text input.

Comment: <div class="_52lr fsm fwn fcg">It's free and always will be.</div>

For the div HTML code, I tried the same , But I can get the text. But for the below code I couldn't get the text. 

<div id="reg_error_inner" class="_58mo" tabindex="0">Please enter a valid email address.</div>

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for this can be:

```java
WebElement error = driver.findElement(By.id("reg_error_inner"));

// Any of these should work
System.out.println(error.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
System.out.println(error.getAttribute("innerText"));
System.out.println(error.getAttribute("textContent"));
```

**Edit**
getText() should work fine. I just tested it in Python.

```
d = webdriver.Chrome()
e = d.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id='reg_error_inner']")
print(e.text)
```

Output: 'Please enter a valid email address.'

Comment: @rocky In that case you must be doing something wrong in your code. I'm unable to check this as you didn't provide any, but getText() works fine for me.